# What is the best way(in case of performance) to find out the user details with maximum salary?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery, query-optimization

We have user details with a column of salary also, how can we print the user details with the maximum salary, I don't want to use the Subquery, and yeah how subquery will reduce the performance.
I know this query is wrong but I want something like this:

```
  select User_name, user_id 
  from dual where salary=Max(salary);
```

Comment: Have you tried using subquery? What is the performance number looking like? what are the number records you have?. What database are you using?
I highly doubt there would be a performance concern no matter how big the data is, in calculating something as simple as max without any joins.

Answer (score 1):

Analytic functions help.

Using a CTE (which is kind of a subquery; don't be *afraid* of it, it doesn't bite and won't affect performance), query might look like this (based on sample Scott's schema):

```
SQL> select ename, sal from emp order by sal desc;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000         --> this is the highest salary
FORD             3000         --> FORD and SCOTT share the 2nd place
SCOTT            3000
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
ALLEN            1600
TURNER           1500
MILLER           1300
WARD             1250         --> WARD and MARTIN are then 9th
MARTIN           1250
ADAMS            1100
JAMES             950
SMITH             800

14 rows selected.
```

Query is then

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select ename,
  3            dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  select ename
  7  from temp
  8  where rnk = 1;

ENAME
----------
KING

SQL>
```

---

Why `dense_rank`? Because two (or more) employees can have the same salary so they "rank" the same. For example, if you want to know whose salary is ranked as 9th, you'd

```
SQL> l8
  8* where rnk = 1
SQL> c/1/9
  8* where rnk = 9
SQL> /

ENAME
----------
WARD
MARTIN

SQL>
```

---

Query you suggested (although wrong, but - I got the idea) looks like this:

```
SQL> select ename
  2  from emp
  3  where sal = (select max(sal) from emp);

ENAME
----------
KING

SQL>
```

And yes, it affects performance because you're fetching data from the same `emp` table twice: once to find the max salary (in a subquery), and then in the *main* query to find who it belongs to.